# Should the number "0" be pronounced "zero" or "oh"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have often heard people say 101, as one-zero-one, and also as one-*oh*-one. Which is correct, and why? Does the difference between British English and American English have to do something with it?

Comment: There's a bug in TomTom-brand GPS systems that makes them say roads such as 202 as "two-west-two".

Comment: Martha: Why is that so?

Comment: @Logophile: like I said, it's a bug. My sister's theory is that the pronunciation was at some point encoded using the International Phonetic Alphabet, which denotes the 'oh' sound with a Greek lowercase omega: ω. Which, as you can see, looks awfully like a W. And a 'W' in the context of road names is most likely an abbreviation for West. ... But this is all supposition.

Comment: ...and actually, I just did a quick search for this bug, and it may have something to do with Quebec/French.

Comment: Martha: Oh I see!!! :p

Comment: Yeah, "Ouest" is French for "West."

Comment: Also, one-nought-one.

Comment: @VikrantChaudhary: There's also "nil", as in, "France defeated Germany, three-nil."

Comment: Note that "0" in a sports score is pronounced "nil" in British English but "nothing" in American English e.g. the Steelers beat the Cowboys 52-0 (fifty-two nothing).

Comment: Threre's "love" too like in tennis "fifteen to love"

Comment: If someone has an e-mail address "1o1@something" (one-oh-one), I guess many people will write it down as "101@something" (one-zero-one) if they heard it spelt on the phone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

American speakers use zero in both conversation and writing. When reciting a string of numbers only, it is acceptable and common for an American to pronounce zero as "oh". But when reciting a string that mixes characters and numbers, it becomes necessary to differentiate between "oh" and zero.

In British English, zero is normally used only in scientific writing. In conversation, British speakers usually say "nought", or to a lesser degree, "oh".

**Edit:** Please review the excellent discussion below for further insight.

Comment: +1.  I wouldn’t quite say ‘zero’ is limited to scientific use in BrE — it’s still fairly frequent in conversational use, though certainly less so than it is in the US.  Otherwise, this answer completely agrees with my experience… although I’d love to see some usage data to back them up!

Comment: Agreed. I should have included a disclaimer that I am an American English speaker.

Comment: @HaL "string of digits", not "string of numbers" (mathematically pendatic, me?  Why of course! ;-)

Comment: You'll also (I think) find that "oh" will only be used within a string of digits.  For example, the usual test of acceleration for a car in the "miles-per-hour" world is "nought to sixty" or "zero to sixty".  "oh to sixty" could be confusing.

Comment: In the US, in zip (postal) codes, almost everybody says "oh" for 0. (eg "Beverly Hills nine-oh-two-one-oh"). At least where I live, the same applies to telephone area codes.

Comment: zero is still used in formal British-English, and where it is important to distinguish between O and 0 (like in technology, science, radio commmunications, etc)

Comment: AFAIK, in British English, "nought" is *much* more common than "oh". (At least in Indian English, it's always "nought" or "zero", never "oh" except occasionally with American influence.)

Comment: The Beverly Hills allusion reminds me of when Jethro Clampett said that he wanted a job as a 'double-nought spy' after watching the latest Bond movie. Bond, of course, being double-zero seven.

Answer (score 9):

Both are correct. But, *zero* is more formal than *oh*. Native speakers, both Americans and Brits, tend to use either of the forms. Limit the use of *oh* colloquially.

The **Oxford English Dictionary** says:
O n. (also **oh**) zero (in a sequence of numerals, especially when spoken).

Answer (score 6):

Zero is a little bit longer to pronounce, hence the "oh".  As an American speaker, I've always heard it pronounced one 'oh' one, though that doesn't make it anymore correct than one zero one or one-hundred and one even.

It also tends to be a little more trendy and/or less formal to use 'oh' (Hawaii Five-Oh for example).

Comment: "Hawaii Five-Oh" and trendy in the same sentence... the world's going crazy ;-)

Comment: On that note, Hwy 401 in Ontario, is always "Four-Oh-One", never "four-hundred and one" or "four-zero-one". But Hwy 400 is always "four-hundred"

Comment: Good point.  Easier (or at least less ambiguous) to say four-hundred than four-oh-oh.

Comment: The freeway in California is definitely "one oh one" (or "the one oh one" near its southern end). But the book is always "one hundred and one Dalmatians".

Answer (score 0):

I also use 'zero' as if I use 'oh' in a string for numbers (i.e. nine-oh-three) it can be mistaken from an eight (nine-eight-three), as there is the tendency to soften or drop the 't' from eight if it is followed by another word, especially if the following word starts with a t sound (or th, d or to a lesser case d or p)

This may be simply due to my Australian accent, but I don't feel this is the case.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, I say 'oh' only if it's a combination of 3 or more numbers (1-oh-9) or money (a dollar oh five). But if it's 1000, I say 'a thousand'.